# Spring Boot - custom annotation inside Component class

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

I'm really newbee in spring philosophy. In our project we have a lot of random strings, to make it's more easily i want to create my custom annotation to inject random String  into field. Example class

```
@Component
public class Tester{

    @InjectRandomString(length = 25)
    private String randomString;
    public void testRandom() {
        System.out.println(randomString);

    }

}
```

And this is my BeanPostProcessor class

```
public class InjectRandomStringAnnotationBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String name) throws BeansException {
        Field[] fields = bean.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            InjectRandomString annotation = field.getAnnotation(InjectRandomString.class);
            System.out.println(field.getName());
            if(annotation != null){
                System.out.println("NOT NULL");

                int length = annotation.length();
                if(length < 0){
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Length is negative");
                }
                String random = UsefulStaff.getRandomString(length);
                field.setAccessible(true);
                ReflectionUtils.setField(field, bean, random);
            }
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

To registre this class i've created @Config class with following Bean

```
@Bean
    public InjectRandomStringAnnotationBeanPostProcessor randomStringPostProcessor(){
        return new InjectRandomStringAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
    }
```

To test it i created Tester object inside RestController

```
@Autowired
Tester tester;

@RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> test(@RequestParam(name = "message") String meString) throws TimeoutException, SocketTimeoutException, SocketException {

        tester.sendMessageToQueue();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(Enums.Error.SUCCESS.toString());
    }
```

But every time i call this method my randomString is equal to null. What am i doing wrong?

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface InjectRandomString {
    int length();
}
```

Comment: This seems like a horrible way to generate random strings. For starters, you can't unit test this, not to mention all this junk code you'll have to maintain. Just create a static utility method and call it good.

Comment: Thank for response, but quistion is not what is the best way to ctreate random data, what am i doing wrong in my beanPostProcessor?

Comment: "but quistion is not what is the best way to ctreate random data" - which is why I didn't post an answer, but a comment. I guess if you're paid by the hour, this is a good use of your time, but I can't say the same about me, so good luck.